# Wi-Fi sleep policy when mobile networks are turned off

Tags: battery, networking, wi-fi

I have a fairly expensive data plan and I don't want my phone to use any of it, so it turned off mobile networks in Settings. When I access the Wi-Fi sleep policy setting, it says it switches to mobile networks when wifi sleeps.

Is that really the case? Does wifi sleep policy override the setting that disabled mobile networks, and eventually use them?

Comment: Just some confusing wording.  What they mean is it will turn WiFi off, and the handset will fall back to using cell data (if available).  It won't actually enable the cell data.

Answer (score 2):

According to my experience, it does not turn mobile networking on. I have Android 2.2 on HTC Desire HD.